# Why babylon add .manifest extension to loadable model?

Tags: javascript, babylonjs

I try load GLTF model by babylon.js:

```
const folder = '/myaddress/';
const modelFile = 'model.gltf';
BABYLON.SceneLoader.Load(folder, modelFile, myEngine, function (scene) {
});
```

I expect the model will be loaded from url `/myaddress/model.gltf`, but Babylon loads the model from url `/myaddress/model.gltf.manifest?1509355427478`.

What is the reason for the behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

js supports caching data in Indexed by. The manifest file is used for this purpose 
More details here: http://doc.babylonjs.com/how_to/caching_resources_in_indexeddb